# about hbase put attribute

Tags: java, hbase

In hbase help, there is exist [put 't1', 'r1', 'c1', 'value', {ATTRIBUTES=>{'mykey'=>'myvalue'}}].
I use it example:

```
put 'person', 'row3', 'info:name', 'Bob Johnson', {ATTRIBUTES=>{'mykey'=>'123456'}}
```

next, I use `"scan 't1', { COLUMNS => ['c1', 'c2'], ATTRIBUTES => {'mykey' => 'myvalue'}}"`, but I couldn't find the "ATTRIBUTES"

.
I don't have any way to find this "ATTRIBUTES".

What operation can I use to query this "ATTRIBUTES"?
Both hbase shell and JAVA API are acceptable...